# Is it possible to use Firebase without variable project ID

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am developing an Android App but have some specially requirements.

I want to allow user to enter their own send_id and API_KEY, but all the guide google offered is to use the google-service.json and fixed id.

I tried manually initial FirebaseApp instance but get null token from FirebaseInstanceID.

So is this possible to manually initial Firebase and works as charm?

Comment: The title is a little bit confusing. By using Firebase. Do you mean the Push Notification Service or the Realtime database only?

Comment: Actually I use push service only now, but I wish to keep possibility to use other service.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be possible. Before GCM or FCM works, the Sender ID and API key must be setup properly. And it's not directly mentioned in the wording to answer this specific question, but as seen in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key) for the API Key:

> **Do not include the API key anywhere in your client code.**

Having the API Key as an input parameter for an Android app violates this and is kind of a security risk itself.

Comment: Sorry, I do not express clearly. The API_KEY I mentioned is not the GCM or FCM key, but the API_KEY included in the google-service.json used to Analysis or others.

Comment: Hi @GhostFlying. AFAIK, regardless of what type of API key you are referring to, it is to be securely stored and kept secret.